# target= out of a iframe but stays in the same browser window?

Tags: php, html, forms

Currently, site A is embedded in a site B's `iframe`. For one .php page, I'd like to jump out of the parent `iframe` when submitting to the page:

```
<form method="post" action="home.php" name="homeForm" target="_blank">
```

However, this will pop up a new window.

Is there a way to jump out of the `iframe` but remind in the same browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to use `target="_parent"` or `target="_top"`.

As per the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16):

> _parent - The user agent should load the document into the immediate FRAMESET
>   parent of the current frame. This
>   value is equivalent to _self if the
>   current frame has no parent.
>
> _top - The user agent should load the document into the full, original
>   window (thus canceling all other
>   frames). This value is equivalent to
>   _self if the current frame has no parent.

However, it should be noted that the use of iframes, etc. isn't a part of the HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 0):

`target="_parent"` this will help you